# get specific values of a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am searching for the best way to get specific values in a multidimensional array. My array looks like this. I dont know how many Arrays i get back so i need this in a foreach.

e.g. I want now to return from every array the [event_budget][0] value. How can i achieve this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event_budget] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bis € 4000
                )

            [event_date] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 27.10.2019
                )

            [event_date_timestamp] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1572134400
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [event_budget] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bis € 500
                )

            [event_date] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 29.10.2019
                )

            [event_date_timestamp] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1572307200
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_map` with `array_column` and `array_shift`

```
$aa = array_map('array_shift',array_column($a, 'event_budget'));
print_r($aa);
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/fKpjY

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways in which you can get your required result.

The most basic :

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach($result as $key => $value){
  $finalArray[] = $value['event_budget'][0];
}
```

The $finalArray will have your required result. You can also use like @rakesh have mentioned.

```
array_map('array_shift',array_column($a, 'event_budget'));
```

It would be great if you have control over the main array. If that is the case you can avoid event_budget to be an array.

If possible, it should be made like this:

---

[event_budget] => Array
(
   [0] => Bis € 500
)

---

[event_budget] => Bis € 500

---

Hope it was helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Hello, i modified the array and solved it with foreach. Thank you for help, but the correct answer came from @rakesh so i accepted his answer

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

```
print_r(array_column($array, 'event_budget'));
```

But as `event_budget` is array too, you need to get columns with index 0:

```
print_r(array_column(
    array_column($array, 'event_budget'), 
    0
));
```

[Full demo](https://3v4l.org/s6ACb).